# Mule 3.7 - CFX error consuming Web Service Consumer

Tags: web-services, soap, mule

I am consuming the webservice https://www.uat.p20.experian.nl/WS_SDPGateway/sdpgateway.asmx?wsdl.

I am getting an error:

**ERROR**

> ERROR 2015-09-21 23:08:04,789 [[experian_spd_sandbox].HTTP_8044.worker.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:

---

```
Message               : COULD_NOT_READ_XML_STREAM. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: byte[]
Type                  : org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
Payload               : [B@df32cd7
JavaDoc               :
```

---

Exception stack is:

1. > Unexpected character '>' (code 62) expected '='
   >   at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [7,21] (com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException)
   >   com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner:647 (null)
2. > COULD_NOT_READ_XML_STREAM (org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault)
   >   org.apache.cxf.databinding.stax.StaxDataBinding$XMLStreamDataWriter:151 (null)
3. > COULD_NOT_READ_XML_STREAM. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: byte[] (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
   >   org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor:163
   >
   > ---

My goal is just to fix the communication and ensure the webservice can be consumed properly from Mule.

Comment: Mule version? Flow config?

Comment: Mule 3.7. please see http://twindat.nl/WS_error.pdf for details.

Answer (score 0):

"Failed to route event via endpoint" sounds more like a network then a parse error.

Can you try to curl the wsdl from the box that is executing the Mule flow?

Comment: curl --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --data @Sample_SPD.xml https://www.uat.p20.experian.nl/WS_SDPGateway/sdpgateway.asmx  from the same machine works just fine. Also using SOAPUI all is just fine.

I am now looking to get some more logging on CXF or the HTTP call itself to get a clue.
Still any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Note I am running Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:
Afterall it was a mistake in the XML message itself. In addition I had to remove the metadata I had added during trouble shooting. So in case you run into the same just go back to basic and first validate the XML message ;-)
Thanks all for getting me there.

Comment: And in addition.....when configuring the WEB SERVICE CONSUMER in Anypoint Studio it automatically fetched the SOAP web service url as non-secure http where the service only accepts https calls !!!!.